# Постоянные ссылки с ID (WP)

Tags: wordpress

Чем чревато добавление в url ID записи?
Например `/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%/`

Comment: Ну можно начать с вопроса: "Чтобы что?". Это не добавит читатебельности и Вы можете иметь определенные проблемы при миграции контента с Вашего сайта или переносе записи, ее экспорте куда-то на другой сайт либо при синхронизации между Вашими же рабочими окружениями и тп. В принципе это первое что пришло на ум.

Answer (score 2):

При любом из нижеперечисленных сценариев ID изменятся. Соответственно при его использовании в урле изменятся и адреса документов.

1. При миграции контента путём импорта.
2. При смене движка.
3. Иногда нужно удалить старый пост/товар/итд и создать новый на этом же адресе.

Этим причины не ограничиваются, но уже их достаточно, чтобы не закладывать мин с отстроченным взрывом.

ЗЫ. Если же по какой-то причине нужно иметь уникальный набор цифр в урл, то это решается по другому. Но надо писать подробности и цели.